# How to fix my CSS to make a responsive layout?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I designed the page with left side navigation, which on the full screen looks fine, however, when I resize it to mobile size, my main content stays in one column and does not fill up full viewport- leaving quite an empty space on the left.

I believe something in media queries might be causing this.
Here is a link: https://codepen.io/sweexee/pen/abvqyOY
Let me know if you can see it and CSS:

```
/* Typography imported from Google Fonts */

header {
  font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
  color: #257ecc;
}

p,
a {
  font-family: Taviraj, serif;
}

/*Generic styles*/

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

html,
body {
  min-width: 290px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  margin: 8px;
  display: block;
}

a {
  background-color: #257ecc;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #cc4d47;
}

p {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

blockquote {
  border-left: 10px solid #257ecc;
  margin: 1.5em 10px;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
}

blockquote:before {
  color: #257ecc;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}

blockquote p {
  display: inline;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #cc4d47;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Navigation styles*/
nav {
  display: block;
}

#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 290px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #257ecc;
  border-right: solid;
  border-color: #828e99;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  #navbar {
    max-height: 275px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
nav > header {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
}

#navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  #navbar ul {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 207px;
  }
}

#navbar ul > li {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: #cc4d47;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

/*Main ccontent styles*/

main {
  display: block;
}

#main-doc {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 310px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 110px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #main-doc {
    margin-left: -10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  #main-doc {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 270px;
  }
}

/* Section styling*/

section {
  display: block;
}

#main-doc header {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

section article {
  color: #3d4247;
  margin: 15px;
}
article {
  display: block;
}

section article > p {
  display: block;
}

section article > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

section article > ul {
  list-style: none;
}

section article > ul li::before {
  content: "\2022";
  color: #257ecc;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  margin-left: -1em;
}

section article > ul > li {
  font-family: "Taviraj", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3d4247;
}

section article > ul > li > a {
  color: #257ecc;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing the issue on mobile, this is what I see: http://screenshot.how/ZllqZF
Are you able to share a screenshot?

Comment: Hey sweexee, welcome on SO. Just after having a quick look: you need adjust `#main-doc margin-left` in mobile mode. It is now fixed to `320px` when viewport size is between 400-815px. And why is it -10px when vp max-width is 400px? Furthermore, the page looks quite nice, but the CSS is overly complicated. Basically you have two main containers: navbar and main. Why not (for example) make your `<body>` a flexbox container with `flex-direction: column` in mobile mode and `flex-direction: row` in desktop mode and get rid of `position: fixed/absolute` etc?

Comment: Check [Codepen MDN Holy Grail](https://codepen.io/fskirschbaum/pen/LVPeJb) for some example code. Quite easy to understand/modify to your own needs....

Comment: Thank you @RenevanderLende! I am just a beginner, so probably overcomplicating my code a bit:D Thank you for your advice I will try them out!

Comment: Quick flexbox 101: an FBL container is either a row of columns (FBL default) or a column of rows, easy to remember! Repeat this 'thought' when nesting containers and ask: is the element I want to insert a row of... or a column of.... Works all the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add margin-left: 0;** in the **#main-doc** in **@media only screen and (max-width: 815px)**
 width media query as below

With margin-left reflection: 310px; # main-doc moves to the right even in the mobile width of the contents.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 815px)
#main-doc {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 0;    /* *** add this *** */
    margin-top: 270px;
}
```

[image]
After adding, your site will look like the following when the mobile width

Answer (score 0):

Your `#main-doc` has `margin-left: 310px;`.
Remove this in your media query concerning `(max-width: 815px)` and you're good!

Comment: It worked! I'm just a beginner coder learning about responsive grids:) Thank you for community support!